# PostgREST custom function flat array instead of key:value

Tags: postgresql, postgrest

I have this custom function querying a group by from a datalist. As a result I receive my unique query result but as nested objects `[{substance: 'value'}]`. It would prefer my response to be `[value, value, value]`.

SQL:

```sql
create or replace function api.substances(substance_group text) returns table(substance text) 
as 'select api.emissions.substance from api.emissions where api.emissions.substance_group = $1 group by api.emissions.substance;'
language sql;
```

Response:

```
[
  {
    "substance": "Arseen"
  },
  {
    "substance": "Benzo[b]fluorantheen"
  },
  ...
]
```

Response required:

```
[
  "Arseen",
  "Benzo fluorantheen",
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to return an array of text(`text[]`) instead of `table(text)` and use the [array_agg](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-aggregate.html) function on the query. Like:

```sql
create or replace function api.substances(substance_group text) returns text[] as $$
  select array_agg(api.emissions.substance)
  from api.emissions
  where api.emissions.substance_group = $1
  group by api.emissions.substance;
$$ language sql;
```